# Run a helper method on a model class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, module, helper

I created a helper method that I want to run on a model class method and getting a method not found error.

lib/model_helper

```
module ModelHelper
  def method_i_want_to_use
    puts "I want to use this method"
  end
end
```

model/foo

```
    class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ModelHelper
    def self.bar
      method_i_want_to_use
    end
end
```

This setup gives me a no method error.

Comment: Do not use helpers in your models, this is not what they are for. Use concern instead.

Comment: @BroiSatse True.. and correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to `extend` the module instead of `include`.

```
extend ModelHelper
```

`include` makes the methods available as instance methods of `Foo`. That means, you can call the method `method_i_want_to_use` on instances of `Foo`, not on `Foo` itself. If you want to call on `Foo` itself, then use `extend`.

```
module ModelHelper
  def method_i_want_to_use
    puts "I want to use this method"
  end
end

class Foo
  extend ModelHelper

  def self.bar
    method_i_want_to_use
  end
end

Foo.bar
# >> I want to use this method
```